# How to print the result of the query in php

Tags: php

I am new to php, I want to print the response of the query, I am getting some records from the database and calculating the average and now I want to echo that Average as Average (column). Below is the query. Can any one help me please?

> SELECT AVG(CLIENT_WORKOUT_LENGTH) from client_workout where
>   MONTH(CLIENT_DATE_OF_WORKOUT)=04 and CLIENT_ID=2;

Thanks In advance!

Comment: If you want to print out the response, just use `->fetch_assoc` -- that is if you are using an mysql(i) object.

Comment: We are happy to help you troubleshoot problems with your code, but there are better sites for basic tutorial help. You may get better results by starting with a PHP/MySQL tutorial or the PHP documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your could try something like this although mysql is deprecated and you shouldn't use it you can use mysqli http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php or pdo http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

```
<?php
 $query = "SELECT AVG(CLIENT_WORKOUT_LENGTH) as Average_WorkOut_Per_Month from client_workout where MONTH(CLIENT_DATE_OF_WORKOUT)=".$month." and CLIENT_ID=".$clientId." "; 
 $result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to execute the query?

```
$sql = "SELECT AVG(CLIENT_WORKOUT_LENGTH) from client_workout where MONTH(CLIENT_DATE_OF_WORKOUT)=04 and CLIENT_ID=2;"
$result=mysql_query($sql);

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<td>".$row['columnX']."</td>";
        //so on so on.
  }
```

Comment: No I want to display the records on my web Interface

Comment: well then echo out the specific columns you want and put em where you want.

Comment: HI here is my code...

Comment: include_once 'dataBaseConnectivityFile.php';
            $clientId=$_REQUEST["client_id"];
            $month=$_REQUEST["month"];
            
            $query = "SELECT AVG(CLIENT_WORKOUT_LENGTH) as Average_WorkOut_Per_Month from client_workout where MONTH(CLIENT_DATE_OF_WORKOUT)="+$month+" and CLIENT_ID="+$clientId+"   ";
            $output = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            print_r($query);

Comment: Could you please help me out with it?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways are there to see the result of query :

1) Use the native SQL interface to execute the query and see the result. For instance, MySQL interface. (An essential step to have a feel before coding in PHP)

2) For PHP, use `mysql-query($sql)` or `mysqli->query($sql)`, then use the associated fetch function to fetch the results into array. Then `echo` the result.

Comment: HI Neeraj, I am using Navicat and the query is showing me the desired output but I have created my own web interface and I want to fetch the same record over there.